# Checkpoint package R not finding dependency

Tags: r, checkpoint

I'm trying to set up a checkpoint using the checkpoint package.

I'm doing a simple example in which I only load `tidyverse` and I run into an error for missing dependencies.

```r
library(checkpoint)
#> Warning: package 'checkpoint' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> 
#> checkpoint: Part of the Reproducible R Toolkit from Microsoft
#> https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/reproducibility/
checkpoint(snapshotDate = "2020-06-12", forceInstall = TRUE)
#> Scanning for packages used in this project
#> No file at path 'C:\...'.
#> - Discovered 3 packages
#> Unable to parse 1 files:
#> - reprex_reprex.spin.Rmd
#> Removing packages to force re-install
#> Installing packages used in this project
#>  - Installing 'tidyverse'
#> tidyverse
#> also installing the dependencies 'tibble', 'broom', 'dbplyr', 'forcats', 'haven', 'modelr'
#>  - Installing 'knitr'
#> knitr
#> checkpoint process complete
#> ---
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Error: package or namespace load failed for 'tidyverse' in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
#>  namespace 'rlang' 0.4.4 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.6 is required
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

According to the documentation, I'd expect the dependencies to install automatically but this seems not to be the case. If I update the `rlang` package on using `install.packages` everything works fine:

```r
library(checkpoint)
#> Warning: package 'checkpoint' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> 
#> checkpoint: Part of the Reproducible R Toolkit from Microsoft
#> https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/reproducibility/
checkpoint(snapshotDate = "2020-06-12", forceInstall = TRUE, auto.install.knitr = FALSE)
#> Scanning for packages used in this project
#> No file at path 'C:\...'.
#> - Discovered 2 packages
#> Unable to parse 1 files:
#> - reprex_reprex.spin.Rmd
#> Removing packages to force re-install
#> Installing packages used in this project
#>  - Installing 'tidyverse'
#> tidyverse
#> also installing the dependencies 'tibble', 'broom', 'dbplyr', 'forcats', 'haven', 'modelr'
#> checkpoint process complete
#> ---
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.2
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.6.2
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 3.6.2
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.6.2
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 3.6.2
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 3.6.3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I believe it might be related to having `rlang` loaded via a namespace (and not attached), but I thought `checkpoint` isolated these issues.

Comment: See if using v1.0 of checkpoint helps. You'll have to install it from Github for now: https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/checkpoint

Comment: You may want to add `sessionInfo()` to your question.

Comment: @jay.sf I think it is related to `rlang` being attached in the namespace. 
However, my understanding was that checkpoint would isolate from that.
Now that I have installed the latest version of `rlang` I have issues reproducing my error. I'll try to look for another package in which I can cause a similar situation and include the `sessionInfo()`.